# how to avoid spark-submit cache

Tags: apache-spark

spark-submit job is put in CDH, there is a weird thing. It always complains a query (XXX in below), but this query is not in the current application, it was an OLD query used it before and deleted. Looks like there is some cache somewhere.

The code is simple, var extract = sqlContext.sql(".....")

How to fix it ? thanks.

```
16/11/13 22:12:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: aggregate at InferSchema.scala:41, took 3.032230 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'XXX' (string and boolean).;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to remove the old jar and rebuild it for execution.